# Java - parsing Google Spreadsheet cells, nothing else

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I'm at the limit of my sanity.

I have been trying to simply parse, simply read a public spreadsheet in Java, using all sorts of Google APIs and libraries, but none of my attepts worked.

Every tutorial I've followed ended up with the writer explicitly writing his google account password in a `String`, which I do not want to do as I'm going to pass my application around to some people.

Is there a way to JUST READ a god-darned Google Spreadsheet using simple calls to the API and no -or minimal- authentication, that does not entail me storing a password in plaintext?

Answer (score -1):

The examples probably show the username/password hard-coded in the program as an expediency.

Your program would have to collect the username/password at runtime by either prompting the user for input or through some sort of configuration file.